# Why are form field entries disappearing after submitting?

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core

I have form that a user submits. For some reason, in our production environment when they click submit, the form is cleared and they lose all that they filled in when they click submit. I've been lost on this for awhile so any input would really help.

I've tried on multiple browsers and this occurs on each one (Chrome, Safari).

The first action creates the view model for the form, the second one takes that data/model and submits an application:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Applicant")]
public IActionResult Application()
{

    var vm = _applicantManager.GetApplicationViewModel(CurrentUser.UserName);

    return View(vm);
}

[HttpPost]
//[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Authorize(Roles = "Applicant")]
public IActionResult Application(ApplicationViewModel model)
{

    var saved = false;

    model = _applicantManager.RebuildApplicationViewModel(model);


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        saved = _applicantManager.SubmitApplication(model, CurrentUser.UserName);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }


    return View(model);
}
```

I'm thinking if I remove the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` that maybe this would solve issue, but am not sure.

Is it possible that the first action needs a route? On testing, it goes to the action with the `HttpPost` attribute when I click submit on my local environment.

**Note**: This is a problem on the production server, this does not occur on the local. This leads me to believe that may a possible IIS setting that needs changed?

JavaScript on the Page:

```
<script>
    require(['jquery', 'jqueryui'], function($, jqueryui) {

    $(function() {


        $("#preHealthAreaDiv input:radio").click(function () {

            var selectedVal = $("#preHealthAreaDiv input:radio:checked").val();

            if (selectedVal == "Yes") {
                $("#preHealthAreaDetail").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#preHealthAreaDetail").hide();
            }
        })

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like its front end related. Try disabling JS and posting the form to see if you get the same issue. If not then you know its JS related. The default action for a form is to navigate away, anything else is custom behaviour. The fact that you expect the form to be populated still, indicates that you have some scripts that override the default behaviour. I'd start there.

Comment: @KieranDevlin I only have one piece of JS though, is it really possible that it could be causing this...? I placed the JS in the question.

Comment: @KieranDevlin If I disable JS it seems to not let me use the "Next" button on my page, and I can't get to the submit button.